# C# add a dictionary in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I am trying to store data in a sorted dictionary with a key and the value being another dictionary.

I have defined a class :

```
public class Search_Config_Out_List
{
    public string _Env { get; set; }
    public string _Interface { get; set; }
    public string _System { get; set; }
    public string _Timeframe { get; set; }
    public string _Dir { get; set; }
    public string _Filename { get; set; }
    public string _LogDir { get; set; }
    public string _LogFile { get; set; }
    public Search_Config_Out_List(string Env, string Interface, string System, string Timeframe, string Dir, string Filename, string LogDir, string LogFile)
    {
        _Env = Env;
        _System = System;
        _Interface = Interface;
        _Timeframe = Timeframe;
        _Dir = Dir;
        _Filename = Filename;
        _LogDir = LogDir;
        _LogFile = LogFile;
    }
}
```

Defining :

```
SortedDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Search_Config_Out_List>> dA = 
        new SortedDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Search_Config_Out_List>>();
List<Search_Config_Out_List> lsSearch_Config_Out_List = new List<Search_Config_Out_List>();
```

At this point i have been looping through an XML file retrieving data. There can be 2 types : 1 for 'Today' and 1 for 'Older' for the same key.

```
 lsSearch_Config_Out_List.Clear();
 lsSearch_Config_Out_List.Add(
        new Search_Config_Out_List(nodeALL.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString(), 
                                   childENV.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString(), 
                                   intALL.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString(), 
                                   intDTL.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString(), 
                                   sDir, 
                                   sFilename, 
                                   sLogDir, 
                                   sLogFile));

//sKey is the key for dA
string sKey = nodeALL.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString() 
                + "-" + childENV.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString() 
                + "-" + intALL.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString();

//sKey2 is the key for the inside Dictionary (possible values are 'Today' and 'Older'
string sKey2 = intDTL.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString();
dLine = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
if (!dLine.ContainsKey(sKey2))
   dLine.Add(sKey2, new List<string>());
//Store in Dictionary
dLine[sKey2].Add(lsSearch_Config_Out_List); "****ERROR has invalid arguments

dA = new SortedDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Search_Config_Out_List>>();
if (!dA.ContainsKey(sKey))
   dA.Add(sKey, new Dictionary<string, Search_Config_Out_List>());
dA[sKey].Add(dLine);     "**ERROR has invalid arguments
```

In the end i want the Dictionary to store something like this:

```
KEY="TEST-1"
   VALUE[0]   KEY="TODAY"
                       VALUE[0] Line1
                       VALUE[1] Line2
                       VALUE[2] Line3
   VALUE[1]   KEY="OLDER"
                       VALUE[0] Line1
                       VALUE[1] Line2 
KEY="TEST-2"
   VALUE[0]   KEY="TODAY"
                       VALUE[0] Line1
   VALUE[1]   KEY="OLDER"
                       VALUE[0] Line1
```

I've tried a few different ways suggested on the internet but i'm either getting an error or when adding the 'Older' key value, it also overrides the 'Today' value. SO i have been struggling with this for a few days.

Any help would be much appreciated. If you can provide an example of correct code that would be advantageous.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: You're calling it like `.Add([value])` instead of `.Add([key],[value])`

Comment: Idk if it's just me but your code is hard to read - maybe I'm just tired. But Mathus is correct, you're missing your `Key` definition. I thought there was a problem with your `Dictionary` declarations too but a few re-reads and I see what's going on.

Comment: The naming conventions you're using is a mess. Consider following the C# guidelines for naming things.

Comment: if i change it to     dLine.Add(sKey2, lsSearch_Config_Out_List); i still get error - Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<eGate_Message_Search_Tool.Search_Config_Out_List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: sorry for naming conventions, but i have been copying/pasting/copying/pasting from suggestions on the internet trying to follow what others have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more then just List to Dictionary

```
dA.Add(sKey, new Dictionary<string, Search_Config_Out_List>());
```

You are adding a New Dictionary, but you need an Instance to Add not the Initialization.

```
        SortedDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, myClass>> dA = new SortedDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, myClass>>();
        Dictionary<string, myClass> lsSearchConfigOutList = new Dictionary<string, myClass>();



        lsSearchConfigOutList.Clear();
        lsSearchConfigOutList.Add("1", new myClass(name:"John", face:"Happy"));
        lsSearchConfigOutList.Add("2", new myClass(name: "Frank", face: "Sad"));
        //sKey is the key for dA
        string sKey = "Test-1";
        //sKey2 is the key for the inside Dictionary (possible values are 'Today' and 'Older'
        string sKey2 = "Today";

        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, myClass>> dLine = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, myClass>> {{sKey2, lsSearchConfigOutList}};
        var dicNew = new Dictionary<string, myClass>() { {sKey2, new myClass("Tom", "Hero")} };

            dA.Add("key2", dicNew);
```

The other class

```
class myClass
{
    public myClass(string name, string face)
    {
        Name = name;
        Face = face;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Face { get; set; }
}
```

It is not your code, but you get the idea, Make a New Object then Add IT to the List, or use inline instantiation.

With this code it comes to 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR9wf.jpg

Comment: After 'Today' has been added, 'Older' will not get added as the primary key sKey would be a duplicate.

Comment: All good. i can add secondary dictionary for duplicate primary key                             if (!dA.ContainsKey(sKey))                                                           dA.Add(sKey, dicNew)                                                                               else  {  dA[sKey].Add(sKey2, null); dA[sKey][sKey2] = (new Search_Config_Out_List(nodeALL.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString(), childENV.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString(), intALL.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString(), intDTL.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString(), sDir, sFilename, sLogDir, sLogFile));

Answer (score 1):

Okay this code is SERIOUSLY hard to read, so this is a bit of guessing in the dark.

First error line:

`dLine[sKey2].Add(lsSearch_Config_Out_List); "****ERROR has invalid arguments`

This tries to add a list to a list. This does not work. Either use the `=` operator to overwrite the value in the dictionary or use `dLine[sKey2].AddRange(...)` to append to the existing list.

Second error line:

`dA[sKey].Add(dLine);     "**ERROR has invalid arguments`

I have absolutely no clue what you're trying to accomplish here (or where for example `diSearch_Config_List` comes from) but you are trying to add a `List` to a `Dictionary` without providing a key.

Comment: if i try                                              dLine[sKey2].AddRange(lsSearch_Config_Out_List);                               i get error   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<eGate_Message_Search_Tool.Search_Config_Out_List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'